# having x axis as month in chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have an sheet "Result" with an table that displays certain data.

In the table I have column A as week number from 1 till 53.

Not all the weeks have the result filled. there are few weeks with no result.

I am trying to generate an Column Stacked chart out of this Table.

While I am extracting, I could see the details are getting overlapped in the chart and there is a lack of visulaization.

I would like to ask, if there is an way I could convert the weeknumber of the X axis of the chart to Month.

Could anyone tell me how I could do it ?

here is the code I am using for my chart

```
Sub chartstatus()
Dim rng, rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim cht As Object
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A53")
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:J53")
Set rng = Union(rng1, rng2)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").ChartObjects.delete
Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=750, _
    Width:=1100, _
    Top:=80, _
    Height:=350)

sh.Select

Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
.SetSourceData Source:=rng
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
cht.Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
cht.SeriesCollection(1).delete
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Result 2017(Percentage)"
End Sub
```

[image: This is how my table looks like with the data, and with column A having the Weeknumber]
[image: with the above code, I am generating an Graph like below.]

Instead of the numbers displayed below, I would like to have the corresponding month name. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: @Could anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column.

In my example I have the week number in Column A and Year in Column B. In Column C I've then used the following formula:

```
=DATE(B1,1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1,1,3))+A1*7
```

Then instead of using the week number column for you chart use your calculated column. Then format the chart axis with a custom format of "mmmm" This will give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

If your week numbers are in `Column A`, use `Column B` as a helper column and enter the below formula,

```
=TEXT(42729+(A1*7),"mmm-yy")
```

[image]

You could use this range for the chart axis. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did it in the same way.  Now.. if you could see. I have 4 time Jan 3 time feb.. and these are again displayed in my graph.. if there a way the graph could get the cumulative result of jan and other months individually ??

Comment: @Jenny Use `sumif` with month as a criteria

Comment: @Jenny in an helper column

Comment: No that is not clear, even though I will have jan once in the helper column, I will have 4 or 5 values for each and everycolumn then

Comment: @Jenny you need to add all the values for each month in your helper column